# python-gnupg's verify_file doesn't like me passing it an _io.BufferedReader

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got the following code:

```
pkgfile = 'package.tar.xz'
sigfile = 'package.tar.xz.sig'

gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='gpg_home')
pkgfile_obj = open(pkgfile, 'rb')
sigfile_obj = open(sigfile, 'rb')
verification = gpg.verify_file(sigfile_obj, pkgfile_obj)
```

This last line gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/daemon.py", line 96, in <module>
    perform_upgrade('http://localhost:8080/update-bundle.tar.xz', 'http://localhost:8080/update-bundle.tar.xz.sig')
  File "bin/daemon.py", line 41, in perform_upgrade
    verification = gpg.verify_file(sigfile_obj, pkgfile_obj)
  File "/Users/alex/Development/realtime.recurse.com/client/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gnupg.py", line 1017, in verify_file
    p = self._open_subprocess(args)
  File "/Users/alex/Development/realtime.recurse.com/client/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gnupg.py", line 832, in _open_subprocess
    startupinfo=si)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1260, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BufferedReader
```

`pkgfile_obj` and `sigfile_obj` are indeed `_io.BufferedReader` instances, but I don't understand why this doesn't work. After all, python-gnupg's own documentation [gives this example](https://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/#verification):

```
verified = gpg.verify_file(stream) # e.g. after stream = open(filename, "rb")
```

That comment seems to match exactly what I'm doing.

Passing in a plain path doesn't work either:

```
verification = gpg.verify_file(sigfile, pkgfile)
```

results in:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I'm on Python 3.6, python-gnupg 0.4.0.

Comment: Might be a mismatch between your fancy new python and the gpg glue library. Just try giving it paths.

Comment: @pvg by "paths" do you just mean a string representing an fs path?

Comment: Yeah. Or maybe the wrapper? Either way, try the other options, since it seems to hate files.

Comment: @pvg no, the source expects a file-like object, apparently. passing a path string results in `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'`. see https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/python-gnupg/src/1c1ef33133ccdd3a4ade10214e71ae124b9e7016/gnupg.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#gnupg.py-991

Comment: That seems to say it wants a file and a filename

Comment: @pvg ohhhh man. thank you so much. if you add that as an answer I'd be happy to accept

Comment: done. gpg integration libraries are poop. you have my condolences.

Comment: @pvg heh, thanks. agreed :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected parameter types for `verify_filename` are a `file`-like object and a string containing a path for the data file. This starts to make more sense when one takes into account that this integration library essentially shells out to a gpg process for most anything it does.